# In skyve, how do I do a OR filter in a list grid?

Tags: skyve

I have a list grid which I'd like to filter based on an "OR"

```
<filterParameter filterBinding="parent" operator="equal" valueBinding="bizId" />
OR
<filterParameter filterBinding="child" operator="equal" valueBinding="bizId" />
```

this provides the "and" example but not a "or" example.
https://skyvers.github.io/skyve-dev-guide/lists/#list-grid-filtering

is it possible to do an OR?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specify a compound conditional operator like AND or OR when using filter parameters in a list grid definition.
You can however

1. use parameters in the list grid definition and create the OR in the filter stanza of the query or
2. write your own list model extension and programmatically add
   compound conditional criteria to the driving document query.

I'll cover option 1 as it is easier and will satisfy your requirement.

In your metadata query add a filter stanza (there are examples of this in admin.xml such as "qEnabledReports" and "qUsersInGroup".

```
<query name="qExample" documentName="<document-name>">
    <description>Example query with filter</description>
    <filter>
        <![CDATA[
            (bean.parent = :bizId OR bean.child = :bizId)
        ]]>
    </filter>
    ...
</query>
```

and then in the grid

```
<listGrid title="Users In Group" query="qUsersInGroup" continueConversation="false" ...>
    <parameter name="bizId" valueBinding="bizId" />
</listGrid>
```

which defines the bizId parameter with the value from the view bean's bizId.